# Multiple User login c# .net application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I am writing a program of login, logout and using timer to calculate how many hours worked.  So what I really want is that whenever a single user logs in, other users should also be able to login, meanwhile the program is running without logout, because it will be calculating the number of hours per each employee. And in the meantime while the users are logged in, it should be able to allow a single user to logout with their own employee number in order to stop the hours worked. So now what I really need is for the multiple users to be able to login in different employee numbers in order it should calculate each employee hours. So the code I’ve posted, what it does when I enter employee number it begins to calculate number of hours, but the problem is that whenever I enter a different employee number it stops the timer and which is something I don’t want, it must begin another timer for each employee/user and logout with their own employee number.
                                                                                                                                     ----------

```
     if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter employee number");
            textBox1.Focus();

        }

        else
        {
            try
            {

                var strconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tk"].ConnectionString;

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strconn);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT employee_number FROM employeedetails WHERE employee_number = @employee_number", conn);



                SqlParameter employee_number = new SqlParameter("@employee_number", SqlDbType.NChar);

                employee_number.Value = textBox1.Text;



                cmd.Parameters.Add(employee_number);


                cmd.Connection.Open();

                SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                if (myReader.Read() == true)
                {
                    search();

                    if (textBox1.TextLength == 4 & radioButton1.Checked == false)
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = myReader[0].ToString();
                        login = DateTime.Now;
                        txtstart.Text = login.ToShortTimeString();
                        txtDate.Text = login.ToShortDateString();
                        radioButton1.Checked = true;
                        textBox1.Text = "";

                    }
                    else if (textBox1.TextLength == 4 & radioButton1.Checked == true)
                    {

                        logout = DateTime.Now;
                        txtend.Text = logout.ToLongTimeString();

                        //display on the textbox
                        logout = DateTime.Now;
                        listBox1.Items.Add("employee number:" + textBox1.Text);
                        listBox1.Items.Add("login duration - Min :" + logout.Subtract(login).Minutes);
                        listBox1.Items.Add("login duration - hour :" + logout.Subtract(login).Hours);
                        listBox1.Items.Add("login duration - mili :" + logout.Subtract(login).Milliseconds);
                        listBox1.Items.Add("login duration - Sec :" + logout.Subtract(login).Seconds);
                        listBox1.Items.Add("--------------------------------------------------------");
                        txtnumberofhours.Text = "min" + logout.Subtract(login).Minutes;

                        radioButton1.Checked = false;
                        textBox1.Text = "";
                        insert();
                    }

                    else if (textBox1.TextLength != 4)
                    {
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enter whatever");
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, "Login Failed...Try again !", "Login Denied", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    textBox1.Clear();
                }
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Dispose();
                }
```

Comment: Don't use timers. Create a new `DateTime` that indicates exactly when the Employee "logged in." When they logout, calculate it there.

Comment: @EBrown you mean replace timer with Datetime?

Comment: There is no "timer" being used..it is already a `DateTime`...

Comment: You should be keeling a `List` or `Dictionary` (probably a `Dictionary` would be better) that has a link of each employee number to the time they logged in. When they login, add a record to the `Dictionary`, when they logout, remove that record. You can also use this to check if an employee is *already* logged in.

Comment: Is this a web app or winforms?

Comment: @srutzky Considering he has `MessageBox.Show(...`, I would safely assume **Windows Forms.**

Comment: @Marcus What are you doing with this data once it's collected? Are you saving it to the database?

Comment: @Marcus Also, I get the feeling this is **not** a complete example. This is only part of *a method* that doesn't tell us anything about how you are actually handling things.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here, in terms of both the code and the approach:

1. In terms of the intended behavior and the testing of it:

   > whenever I enter a different employee number it stops the timer and which is something I don’t want

   Are you using the same browser session or WinForm window to do this testing of different employee numbers? If so, is that the intended usage? Normally each employee would have their own session or window/app. And in that scenario, it *should* work. But when testing in the same session or window/app it would naturally overwrite the old `employee_number.Value` with the newer value. This code is only meant to handle a single `employee_number`. If you needed to use the same session or window/app for multiple `employee_number`s, then you would need to store them in a collection such that each one can have its own `login` and `login` values.
2. Why would you `SELECT employee_number ... WHERE employee_number = @employee_number`? Just to validate that it is a valid `employee_number`? Seems odd otherwise since you are selecting the value that you are passing in, hence you already had it.
3. Since you only seem to be confirming the validity of the entered `employee_number`, why overwrite what they enter with that same value coming back from the DB? This line: `textBox1.Text = myReader[0].ToString();` makes no sense since again, the value in `myReader[0].ToString()` came from there: `employee_number.Value = textBox1.Text;`
4. This makes no sense: `cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT...` since you already had it instantiated 2 lines above in: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();`. All this line does is remove the effect of this line: `cmd.Connection = conn;`. Instead, just use:

   ```
   SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT employee_number FROM employeedetails WHERE employee_number = @employee_number";
   ```
5. You do not need to test booleans by using `== true` or `== false`. You can simply use: `if (myReader.Read())`, `& !radioButton1.Checked` (for `== false`), and `& radioButton1.Checked` (for `== true`)
6. You are not properly handling the external resources by either placing them in a try / finally or at least a `using()` construct (which is a macro that gets replaced with a try / finally). The `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` all need to be disposed via their `Dispose()` method. And while you are calling `conn.Dispose();`, that line will be never be reached if an exception occurs anywhere prior to that line.
7. Instead of testing for `if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)`, test for it *not* being closed since there are other valid states: `if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)`
8. When getting a value out of a result set (i.e. the `SqlDataReader`), use `myReader.GetString(0)` instead of the current `myReader[0].ToString()`
9. When creating a `SqlParameter` for a string datatype, please specify the max length *according to what the actual field is defined as*: `new SqlParameter("@employee_number", SqlDbType.NChar, 50);` instead of the current `new SqlParameter("@employee_number", SqlDbType.NChar);`. And did you mean to use `NChar` instead of `NVarChar`?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't a web application.

Comment: Not just that, but this is **likely** a type of time-clock. Generally speaking, time clocks are very basic and don't require session-handling. The employee enters their `clock-number` and presses **Clock In** or similar.

Comment: Also, the `SELECT employee_number ...` has more advantages than that: if the employee enters non-sanitized data, then this will **also** sanitize their entry *because* he is using SQL Parameterized Queries.

Comment: @DavidG Even if not, it is effectively the same if it's a WinForm that doesn't exit but just refreshes.

Comment: @EBrown sanitize how? It would only "proper"-case the value, assuming it allows for mixed-case anyway. Any other characters would cause the query to not match at all, in which case it is the same as a simple `IF EXISTS` that returns a BIT / bool.

Comment: @srutzky I never said it was the *best* approach to the problem, simply that it guarantees that the `employee_number` will **never** have invalid characters/strings/etc. It also allows him to **easily** add other fields in the future. I would worry less of his SQL statement (especially considering that he properly used SQL Paramterized Queries) and instead worry of his inappropriate choice for variable names (`textBox1`), and the fact that this *is not* a complete example. We are missing multiple critical methods.

Comment: @EBrown I agree with most of what you are saying, especially that there are better ways of handling this concept, however, I still feel it is important to provide guidance on how to better structure any code, regardless of concept. And if more fields are needed to be returned in the future that is fine, but changing it to an IF EXISTS to return a BIT / bool doesn't take away from the DB interaction structure. Also, invalid characters will not be sanitized outside of any equivalences for casing and/or accents, depending on the collation. But an extra ";" will be a login failure regardless.